# Formatting html.ep

Tags: html, perl, formatting, indentation

Is there any tool available to just format (remove whitespace and indent correctly) an *.html.ep file?

Its a template file of a perl app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this program:

http://users.rcn.com/creitzel/tidy.html#tidyui

Hopefully its what you are looking for, if I understand you correctly :o)